# SVN Commit errors because of file move (rename)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

There isn't much more frustrating that dealing with SVN when it won't commit. Here's the error message that I'm getting:
[image]

I've done everything I can think of and torn out what little hair I have left. I've read the other suggestions that were posted on Stackoverflow. This problem started when I allowed Visual Studio 2010 to rename a namespace. I know I got everything back to where it was but SVN isn't convinced.

Here is the SVN Status (better screen shot):
[image]

Comment: Show `svn status` output for the whole working copy or a screenshot of TortoiseSVN displaying the list of pending changes.

Comment: Do you mean Log? Or where is svn status?

Comment: Not sure if Visual Studio 2010 took care of .svn folders while renaming ?

Comment: @IndraUprade the problem has nothing to do with ".svn" folder. And not "folders". It's a single folder at the root of the working copy.

Comment: @zetar I mean `svn status` command or this TortoiseSVN dialog: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-2 Checking the status of the working copy will show you why the error occurs. BTW, don't you use AnkhSVN or VisualSVN in the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AnkhSVN in the IDE

Comment: @zetar then it should take care of renames and other file operations automatically. I can't tell for sure without seeing the WC's status, but the problem is that your commit does not include REMOVE file operation, but includes ADD only. Renames in SVN are REMOVE followed by ADD with internal link betwreen removed and added item.

Comment: The problems seem to be with the last 5 files in the updated SVN Status screen grab.

Comment: @zetar there is also a file with "missing" status.

Comment: I found the file... it's there.

Answer (score 1):

You made some operation in Visual Studio that resultsd in renaming or moving some file to `../CourierReportingEnemy.Designer.cs` (check the error message). Commit of such change must include 2 operations: remove (removing original file) and add (re-adding it in new place or with new name) with a link between the two operations. However, the REMOVE part of this change is not included with your commit by some reason.

Try committing from the root of the Subversion working copy (e.g. your solution's root) and make sure that the commit includes all the necessary changes.

**Update:**

It looks like that there is a problem. The move source `Messenger.cs*` files are non-versioned now. However they should be marked as deleted. There is a chance that AnkhSVN had troubles to translate Visual Studio's operation to Subversion, but I'm not sure.

I'd suggest to start from scratch and re-do your namespace rename. However, there is a chance that [Repair moves/renames](https://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html) feature of TortoiseSVN will help.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I accidentally renamed Messenger.cs to CourierReportingEnemy... etc. No luck in committing from the root (or at any other place). Should I try renaming the CourierReportingEnemy files?